# Occasional StackOverflowError in Recursive Calculation

Tags: java, eclipse

When executing the code pasted below in Eclipse, approximately 1 out of 3 times I encounter the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at src.Adder.recursiveSumAllNumbersUpTo(Driver.java:33)
    at src.Adder.recursiveSumAllNumbersUpTo(Driver.java:37)
    ... *(there are 1024 lines in this stack)*
```

The other 2 times, it spits out the result as intended (the times vary slightly between each run):

```
Recursive: 467946
Non Recursive: 61282
Difference between recursive and non-recursive: 406664
Sum from recursive add: 19534375
Sum from non-recursive add: 19534375
```

Why does the exception only happen (seemingly) ~30% of the time?

Here's the code:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Adder adder = new Adder();
        int valueToSumTo = 6250;

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int raSum = adder.recursiveAddAllNumbersUpTo(valueToSumTo);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long raDif = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Recursive: " + (raDif));

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int nonRaSum = adder.nonRecursiveAddAllNumbersUpTo(valueToSumTo);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long nonRaDif = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Non Recursive: " + (nonRaDif));

        System.out.println("Difference between recursive and non-recursive: " + (raDif - nonRaDif));
        System.out.println("Sum from recursive add: " + raSum);
        System.out.println("Sum from non-recursive add: " + nonRaSum);
    }
}

class Adder {

    public int recursiveAddAllNumbersUpTo(int i) {

        if (i == 1) {
            return i;
        }

        return i + recursiveAddAllNumbersUpTo(i - 1);
    }

    public int nonRecursiveAddAllNumbersUpTo(int i) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int num = 1; num <= i; num++) {
            count += num;
        }

        return count;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime a recursive method calls itself, everything goes to the stack and algorithm such as yours requires a very deep stack.

To solve your problem, you should increase your Stack Size.

You can do that by calling the JVM with the -Xss parameter.

If you are using Eclipse you can do that by doing the following:

1. Right click your project -> Run as -> Run Configurations;
2. Go to the Arguments tab; At the VM arguments, write: "-Xss4m"

Try a bigger stack if that configuration is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for providing a fix to the issue; however, I'm actually interested in understanding why I receive the exception _occasionally_ / in a non-deterministic fashion. What's going on behind the scenes here with Eclipse / JVM?

Comment: Your program is single threaded but the JVM uses other threads to make it work, gc for example. With the current configuration, your program is very close to the limit to the Stack Size available. It is a racing condition problem, sometimes you have enough stack, sometimes you don't, because some other thread may be using it a little bit. System.out.println, for example, usse some stack itself. Try adding another System.out.println printing "i" at each recursive method call and you'll get the Stackoverflow more often. It is all empirical, someone could point documentation or complement this.

Comment: I tried both increasing the stack size (-Xss4m) and adding the Sysout.out.println(i) at each recursive call. Based on this information, I suppose that the JVM internally handles the stack size, and we shouldn't make assumptions about how large it is. If we need something larger, then we must indicate it using the -Xss parameter. Thanks for your help  @pablosaraiva !

Answer (score 0):

try to have a look on if can be usefull:

FROM (http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=411)

> Java stack size myths
>
> How Java uses the stack is basically
>   undocumented. So we developers are left with finding out ourselves.
>   Today I wrote some interesting test code, that delivers surprising
>   results. For my tests I used Sun JDK 1.5.0_12 under RedHat Enterprise
>   Linux 3.
>
> First I wanted to know the stack size that the VM chooses for threads.
>   I found that the ulimit -s parameter has no direct influence on the
>   stack size chosen by the VM. The default is apparently 512kb, and can
>   be changed freely with the -Xss and -XX:ThreadStackSize parameters.
>   But I could not find a difference in behaviour between those
>   parameters. They appear to do the same thing. Further I found that
>   this Linux machine is able to create new threads at a rate of about
>   5000 per second.
>
> I performed these tests by creating new threads and setting them
>   asleep in a blocking wait call immediately. I kept creating threads
>   until the VM ran out of memory. With 512k stacks the number of threads
>   was around 3700, for 256k stacks around 7300, for 128k around 13700.
>
> That leads to the following memory consumption by the stacks:
>        3700 x 512kB = 1850MB
>        7300 x 256kB = 1825MB
>        13700 x 128kB = 1713MB
>
> Of course a 32-bit process is limited to 4GB of address space (minus 1
>   or 2 GB for the kernel). So it is only natural that the memory is
>   close to these 2GB minus the heap size. (Note that Stack is never
>   allocated from the heap.)
>
> Next I tested how deep I could call into a recursive method until I
>   get stack overflows. I did this by modifying the initial program, so
>   that each thread would recurse into a method until it hit stack
>   overflow, then fall asleep. The thread recorded the maximum recursion
>   depth. That's where I got really weird results. Especially with the
>   server VM the maximum depth varies over a wide range between 1750 and
>   5700 calls (128k stacks)! That's far from constant, which would have
>   been my first guess. With the client VM the number is generally lower
>   but doesn't vary that much: between 1100 and 1650.
>
> Also the maximum depth seems to be lower at the beginning of the test
>   and increases toward the end.

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers. That's just delegating the answering to someone else. Post the content of that webpage in the body of your answer.

Comment: @arshajii: you're correct that link-only answers are discouraged. But simply copying the linked-to content is not usually allowed (for copyright reasons). Paraphrasing and summarizing the most relevant parts would be the best course of action (in addition to the link).

Answer (score 0):

play with the stack size : `-Xss32m` allows 32 Mo for the stack.
Note: AFAIK, java doesn't handle (why?!) the tail recursion optimization.

Comment: Java definitely doesn't handle tail recursion (yet). I'm unsure as to whether that'll change in Java 8, but I think I've heard some noise to that effect.